# How to specify a user id and password for Visual Studio Code with an authenticating proxy?

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-code

How to specify a user id and password for Visual Studio Code with an authenticating proxy?

I've seen the [Proxy Server Support](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/supporting/faq#_proxy-server-support) on the main VS Code site, but this only mentions two settings ...

```
"http.proxy": "http://10.203.0.1:5187/"
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

I've set these, but still no luck, e.g. I can't install extensions ... can't even get a list of them

I suspect it's our proxy, as it needs a user id and password  :-(

So how can you set these values?

Comment: The answer below does not work anymore. Instead they introduced a new configuration parameter named "http.proxyAuthorization" but this does not work. `Refused to set unsafe header "Proxy-Authorization"`. It is already reported: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17502

Comment: Reported doesn't mean fixed... or even acknowledged. Still waiting for the fix after more than 4 months.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Set credentials inside the proxy url:

```
http://username:password@10.203.0.1:5187/
```

**WARNING: Setting your password in plaintext in a file can easily lead to your account being compromised. Further it might violate your companies data security guidelines. https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/256.html**

Comment: Excellent, worked a treat ... now why don't they have that in the documentation  :-(

Comment: @SteveC I suppose because this is an standard procedure of basic access authentication, named url encoding, but you could make them a suggestion to include it in the docs.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Apart from it not working it's probably not good to have your username and password in cleartext in your settings. Using CNTLM you can save the hash and do without this.

Comment: Adding proxy url with port alone is enough in latest vscode 1.78.2 No need to enter user credentials.

Answer (score 33):

If you don't want to store your credentials in the settings file, fiddler can be used to proxy the call to the proxy. Furthermore, I believe the above only works for proxy servers using basic authentication, the following should work for NTLM.

**VSCode** Open Settings File:

> %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json

add the following:

```
{
    "http.proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
}
```

**Fiddler** Confirm fiddler settings:

[image]
[image]

**Fiddler** Ensure Fiddler set to automatically authenticate:

[image]

**VSCode** Extensions should now be online:

[image]

---

**Update**

This is now no longer required following implementation of [PR #22369](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/22369) which was implemented in version 1.15 [Proxy server authentication](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_proxy-server-authentication).

In my case I still needed to add:

```
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

Comment: I used fiddler but needed to use Customize Rules... OnBeginRequest "if (m_AutoAuth) {oSession["X-AutoAuth"] = "domain\\username:password";}"

Comment: It would be nice, if vs code provides a setting to specify a ca like npm does, so we don't have to set strictssl to false. See issue on github [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9790?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container)

Answer (score 8):

My favorite response here is David Martin's suggestion of using Fiddler.  But in case that is not something you want to undertake, below is how to set your credentials for the proxy.

To specify DOMAIN + username + password: (It will likely not work with a slash, so use %5C in the place of the slash as shown below)

```
// The proxy setting to use. If not set will be taken from the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables
"http.proxy": "http://DOMAIN%5Cusername:password@proxy_name_or_ip:port",
"https.proxy": "http://DOMAIN%5Cusername:password@proxy_name_or_ip:port",

// Whether the proxy server certificate should be verified against the list of supplied CAs.
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
```

To specify just username + password:

```
// The proxy setting to use. If not set will be taken from the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables
"http.proxy": "http://username:password@proxy_name_or_ip:port",
"https.proxy": "http://username:password@proxy_name_or_ip:port",

// Whether the proxy server certificate should be verified against the list of supplied CAs.
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
```

Comment: I used this but still does not work.Is there anything else ?

Comment: Man, you saved me! I used "\\" in a string instead of "%5C". As soon as I replaced back slashes with "%5C", everything worked! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5):

The venerable CNTLM could help you.  You give it your credentials, tell it about the upstream proxy, run it on your local machine, then point VS to the proxy at http://localhost:3128.

http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

It's a handy solution for any application that doesn't support authenticated proxies.

Answer (score 5):

I really like the solution David Martin posted (further below) using Fiddler, however I wanted to figure out how to use `http.proxyAuthorization` and here is my solution considering you are OK to have credentials saved in base64 encoded format in the `settings.json` file.

**WARNING:** Saving credentials in base64 encoded format is certainly better than plain text, however consider base64 encoding as obfuscation not an encryption and the account can still be compromised - use at your own risk. Consider modifying the ACL of the settings file to reduce read access to it.

**Step 1**: Encode your credentials using the code below:

```
var s = @"DOMAIN\user:pass";
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```

> RE9NQUlOXHVzZXI6cGFzcw==

**Step 2**: Update VS Code settings by adding `http.proxyAuthorization` using the base64 encoded value from above:

```
{
    "https.proxy": "https://internal-proxy.corp.net:8080",
    "http.proxyAuthorization": "Authorization: Basic RE9NQUlOXHVzZXI6cGFzcw=="
}
```

**Step 3**: Secure the `settings.json` by updating it's ACL

> Since you have stored credentials in the file to increase the security you can modify the ACL of the settings file by removing the local administrators group - make sure only you can read this file. I used the following PowerShell script to remove the local admin group for example:

```
#Requires -Version 5.1
# PowerShell 5.1 min version required for the code below
$settings = "$env:appdata\Code\$env:username\settings.json"
$acl = (Get-Item $settings).GetAccessControl('Access')
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true) # removes the ACL inheritance
$accesToRemove = $acl.Access | ?{ $_.IsInherited -eq $false -and $_.IdentityReference -eq 'BUILTIN\Administrators' }
$acl.RemoveAccessRule($accesToRemove)
Set-Acl -AclObject $acl $settings
```

Comment: The easiest way for me (because I am not a JS developer) was to open Chrome dev tools console, and
```
let utf8Encode = new TextEncoder();
var bytes = utf8Encode.encode("foo:bar");
btoa(bytes);
```

Comment: Error: InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method named 'GetAccessControl'. Seems your code to change the ACL is not working (tested on PowerShell 7.2.2).

Comment: Update: Seems to work on PowerShell 5.1

Comment: This is not working for me. I am able to connect via Postman but not via VSCode. I am using the same proxy values only

Comment: You can encode your credentials with PowerShell with the following code:
$credentials = 'DOMAIN\user:pass'
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($credentials)
$encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$encodedCredentials

Answer (score 4):

Please take ref to this article.
https://taeguk.co.uk/blog/working-in-visual-studio-behind-the-firewall/

Let’s assume my NTLM login is DOMAIN\User Name and my password is P@ssword!
The format for the credentials needs to be DOMAIN\User Name:P@ssword!, but you need to URL Encode the user name and password.
A simple online URL encoded can translate your username and password to: DOMAIN%5CUser%20Name and P%40ssword!.
Piece all this info into a single string like so: http://DOMAIN%5CUser%20Name:P%40ssword!@proxy-cluster.fqdn.local:8881
Then add this into your User Settings in File, Preferences against the "http.proxy" value:
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "http.proxy": "http://DOMAIN%5CUser%20Name:P%40ssword!@proxy-cluster.fqdn.local:8881"
}

Comment: This worked for me from behind corporate firewall with VSCode 1.9.1. The differentiating factor was the URL Encode suggestion.. Thank you @Kiki.J.Hu.

Answer (score 2):

"http.proxy": "http://DOMAIN//USER:PASSWORD@wsg.test.com:8080".
Do not forget to add the port.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command and replace the username,password and ip address of you proxy:port

> PS C:\Users\rathakrishnan> npm config set proxy http://username:password@172.18.10.27:3128
>
> PS C:\Users\rathakrishnan> npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

in Visual Studio Code (my version is 1.32.3) you write a request, i.e.

```
### my request
GET https://defdomain.prefix.com/app/resource
Authorization: bXl1c2VyOnVzZXIyMkBwYXNzd29yZA==
```

Wherefore the Authorization header is of type "Basic base64encoded" and consists of
myuser:user22@password (username:usercredentials) base64 encoded. Thats all.