# All of my .json files have problems loading reference/schema from schemastore.azurewebsites.net

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm working in VS Code and started getting this error yesterday.  All of my json files have this error, not just a few.  If I remember right there was an update to the program yesterday or the day before.  Did the update break something or reset a setting that I forgot I had set?

When looking this up, people are talking about downloading the schema and using it locally, but I would prefer not to have to do that and would instead like to find out why this broke?

I am using a proxy, but as far as I know that hasn't changed.  Here's the exact error I'm getting.

Problems loading reference 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': Unable to load schema from 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': Unable to connect to https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 168.62.224.13:443

Comment: restart vscode, it helped me with the same issue.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that and it didn't work.  Even restarted my computer.

Comment: You need to set your proxy.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730040/how-to-specify-a-user-id-and-password-for-visual-studio-code-with-an-authenticat and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: go to the terminal, clear the terminal(ctrl/cmd + c), write, npm install/yarn add, then close the vsc/any text editor(at this phase it will still have the error). restart the terminal and the error will be gone(code .), It is caused by some squishy bug so re-installing the module clears the bug.

Comment: How did you see the full error log? I can't find it any of the output windows.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Open User settings of visual studio code through the command palette:

1. Press <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Type `user settings`.
3. Select `Preferences:Open User Settings` from drop down
4. Put below code and modify accordingly:

```
"http.proxy": "http://username:password@hostname:port/",
"http.proxyAuthorization": null,
"http.proxyStrictSSL": true
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't help. VS Code v1.27.2 (user setup)

Comment: this solve my isssue on windows 7 and vscode v 1.31. Thanks. yes we need to restart the vscode after updating the settings.json

Comment: Thanks, this works on VS Code v1.50.1.0 with just "http.proxyAuthorization" and "http.proxyStrictSSL". I didn't add "http.proxy".

Comment: worked only set the ("http.proxyAuthorization": null)

Answer (score 112):

I'm behind my company's proxy which I don't know the details because it's everything automatic, and this problem have bug me for some time.

I'm not sure whether this is an universal solution but according to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/65118#issuecomment-447521570), the `http.proxySupport` setting is defaulting to *"override"*.

I turn this setting *off* and the errors disappeared:

```
"http.proxySupport": "off"
```

Comment: This worked instantly. I didn't have to restart, close offending editors, or fiddle with stuff!

Comment: It worked instantly for me too. Then the next day the same warning pops up, I check the `"http.proxySupport"` setting and it's still `off`, I tutn it `on` and the warning disappears. Turning off that setting is definitely not the solution. (You can keep my upvote though)

Comment: In my case, the proxy support was hiding that the real problem was in settings.json. Turning it off showed the real problem. Once resolved, I reset the setting and everything was fine.

Comment: This worked for me, despite not having any proxy or not every having used one.

Comment: Yay!  This worked for me too, not using a proxy either but this setting obv was the issue.

Answer (score 75):

Just close your VsCode Editor and open it again. That should fix the error.

Comment: This work for the problem of initiating package without internet of loss of internet connection

Comment: IMHO this should be accepted answer! In most cases you do not manually configure proxies.

Comment: The same "answer" (more like a comment) has been provided a year before this, in the comments of the question itself (up). There is no need to convert someone's comment, into an answer, without adding anything, and also doing this as year after.

Comment: @vsync I respectfully disagree. I didn't see this answer in the comments but I did find it here. Also answers in the comments cannot be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: *"Answers in the comments cannot be marked as the correct answer"* - helpful content is irrelevant if is a comment, and answer, or a "selected" answer. What makes a an answer is writing more than a few words. Also, this "answer" is more of something to try, like telling your mom to restart her computer because of some weird error you don't know how to deal with. This isn't a serious answer which explains why this happens and why/how the fix works. It also didn't work on my case. The one by "Aleksandr Sukhanov" is better, because it is a permanent solution that can be understood.

Comment: i had this problem after syncing on github, btw, with ur solution the problem was gone!

Comment: Sorry but what is the issue why I had to reopen vscode

Answer (score 52):

I just turned off the checkbox `schema download` and the error goes away.

Press F1 and follow  `open user settings/user/extensions JSON`

Comment: Unchecking und then checking it again worked for me...

Comment: @Ini this worked for me after I checked and unchecked on one project, but for the other, I had to do that and restart vsc for the warning to go away

Comment: `"json.schemaDownload.enable": false` in `settings.json`

Comment: Unchecked it and worked for me

Comment: Now there error in the `Problems` tab changed to: *Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/eslintrc': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/eslintrc': Downloading schemas is disabled through setting 'json.schemaDownload.enable'.*

Comment: @vsync make sure your internet works fine, and try re-enabling the option

Comment: I don't want to ever enable this option. I don't care about downloading schemas, they are useless to me. I don't work behind a company's firewall and have no control if the policy disallows some urls for those schemas.

Comment: My connection was bad for a few days and I knew the error was because vscode cannot download the thing, this solution was right on the spot. Restarting also works but +1 for just simply ticking a checkbox on vscode settings.

Answer (score 25):

I was facing following issue with Angular 6:

> Problems loading reference 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': Unable to load schema from 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': Unable to connect to https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json. Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

I added following properties at the end of the User Settings File and worked for me:

```
"http.proxy": "",
"http.proxyAuthorization": null,
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

Comment: Verified to be working on VS Code v1.27.2 (user setup)

Comment: Funny thing, is that I commented this code and the problem didn't return anymore.

Comment: This works if you are in a secure VED with no outside access.

Answer (score 23):

Add this to your `settings.json`. Your problem will be solved! Plus this works for me.

```
"json.schemas": [
    {
      "fileMatch": ["/package.json"],
      "url": "https://json.schemastore.org/package",
      "schema": true
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Correct path: `https://schemastore.org/json/package` https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/issues/1375

Comment: @iegik no - https://json.schemastore.org/package is correct - the one you link is for humans. Why would https://json.schemastore.org/package be incorrect? it resolves without redirection for me.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this issue by turning off proxy support in VS Code.

Open *Settings* and search for *proxy support* at the top. The only option shown should then be the one you want to switch from *Override* (which is the default) to *off*:

> PS: You can also locate settings by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> and entering *user settings*.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Well i didnt like the idea to set "http.proxyStrictSSL": false, so i started searching, and i found this  [Issue](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/issues/12) on SchemaStore site from azure. After seeing this i concluded that my proxy was getting some problem with the certificate and authentication. What i did was change all "https" to "http" in the following session of package.json file(Mine was on this path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\typescript-basics\package.json).

```
"jsonValidation": [
  {
    "fileMatch": "tsconfig.json",
    "url": "http://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/tsconfig.json"
  },
  {
    "fileMatch": "tsconfig.json",
    "url": "./schemas/tsconfig.schema.json"
  },
  {
    "fileMatch": "tsconfig.*.json",
    "url": "http://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/tsconfig.json"
  },
  {
    "fileMatch": "tsconfig.*.json",
    "url": "./schemas/tsconfig.schema.json"
  },
  {
    "fileMatch": "typings.json",
    "url": "http://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/typings.json"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5):

please follow the step below to solve this problem:

1. Open the folder where **package.json** file present
2. Type `npm install` from cmd
3. restart VS code or any IDE that you use.

Comment: Made no difference. Why do you think it would?

Comment: Because a messd up package.json can lead to this issue. I'm personally experiencing a similar problem because in my project there's some version of some module that needs to be there but doesn't get along with some other module. In previous versions of the same project, with older modules version, we had no problem whatsoever, it was introduced by updating the modules

Answer (score 3):

I tried every setting - the only one which works is adding this to `settings.json`:

```json
  "json.schemas": [
    {
      "fileMatch": [
        "/package.json"
      ],
      "url": "https://json.schemastore.org/package",
      "schema": true
    },
  ]
}
```

Note, using the HTTP URL doesn't work - it just ignores the URL.

Answer (score 3):

It's issue of opening the vs code using command line or any type of terminal

for avoid this issue.

> **Just restart the vs code or close the vs code and open again**

Answer (score 2):

If you still want the proxy support to work, just disable the `proxyStrictSSL`. Don't need to adjust other settings.

Comment: `"http.proxyStrictSSL": false` in `settings.json`

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in setting.json file

```
    "http.proxy": "",
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

To Open **setting.json** file use the below step

1. Press **F1**
2. Type User Setting and then select **Preferences:Open User Settings**

Then click on **Edit Setting.json** link
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against this for longer than I care to admit, I just needed to add the `proxyAuthorization` value for my Base64 encoded credentials, and did not need the `proxy` or `proxyStrictSSL` values.

I already had my proxy correctly configured in my environment variables. It only has the domain and port, not my credentials, ex. "HTTP_PROXY" "http://example.com:port/".

I used this C# code in LINQPad to get the `proxyAuthorization` value from my credentials:

```
var pw = "user@example.com:password";
var base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pw));
base64Encoded.Dump();
```

This is what I have in my user `settings.json`, using the encoded string from the above code dump.

```
"http.proxyAuthorization": "BASE64_ENCODED_VALUE"
```

**Note:** I believe that if I didn't need the full username with email address in the credentials for our proxy to let me out, I could have used an above solution. But since I did, this was the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve just delete this setting

```
"http.proxy": "http://.......",
```

Comment: Review: it would be helpful if you mentioned the name and location of the settings file. Otherwise: OK

Answer (score 0):

For me this works  the Azure Storage Emulator stopped working ;-(

To start the Azure Storage Emulator:

Select the Start button or press the Windows key.
Begin typing **Azure Storage Emulator**.
Select the emulator from the list of displayed applications.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator

just do the 3

**in CMD**

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init         
AzureStorageEmulator.exe start      
AzureStorageEmulator.exe status
```

BAM all worked

Answer (score 0):

you need your server up and running in order to load schema from https://json.schemastore.org/stylelintrc.json, seems your server is off that is why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

delete .dart_tool folder in project root. After than reload visual stodio code.

resolved my issue: "name" marked with red line.

Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/pubspec.json': Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details.YAML(768)

Answer (score -1):

for me turns out that the problem was due to `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` being deprecated in VSCode.
these are the steps i followed to fix it :

- Open command palette (CTRL + Shift + P)
- Search "Preferences: Open "User Settings" (the JSON file)"
- find this field => `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` delete it and type this instead inside of `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows"`:

````
  "PowerShell": {
    "source": "PowerShell",
    "icon": "terminal-powershell"
  },
  "Command Prompt": {
    "path": [
      "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
      "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
    ],
    "args": [],
    "icon": "terminal-cmd"
  },
  "Git Bash": {
    "source": "Git Bash"
  }
},```

if you want to disable PowerShell, just set its value to null
````