# Problems creating Node's package.json file in Vs code

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-init

[node package.json error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CJCB.jpg)

Problems loading reference "https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json": Unable to load schema from "https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json":getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND schemastore.azurewebsites.net.

Pls am having this error anytime I try creating package.json file for my node project.. And am using windows laptop and also using Vs code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All of my .json files have problems loading reference/schema from schemastore.azurewebsites.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056000/all-of-my-json-files-have-problems-loading-reference-schema-from-schemastore-az)

Comment: could this error prevent packages from been installed??