# Babel unable to load schema

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am watching a video and the video says that you write
this code in .babelrc:

```
{
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

to transform the es6 code I wrote to common js code that node js can execute. But the problem is that it is unable to load schema from that code above.

Comment: "*load schema*"? What schema? What is the exact error message? And what command/tool are you running that emits it?

Comment: The error message shows that the first curly bracket is the error and the exact error message is: unable to load schema from 'https:/json.schemastore.org/babelrc'. Also the command I used was: npx babel-node src/server.js

Comment: This sounds like [an error from the vscode editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49056000/1048572) not from `babel-node`?