# Cannot connect to marketplace VS Code on Ubuntu 16.04 (Probably proxy Issue)

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy

When I try to connect to the visual studio marketplace, VSCode return an error: "We cannot connect to the Extensions Marketplace at this time, please try again later."

[image: vs code screenshot]

When looking at `Help->Toggle Developer Tools`, I see the following error:

`marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`

Note:
This is the latest version (Version: 1.45.1-1589445302)

Comment: did u found any solution?

Comment: I did :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730040/how-to-specify-a-user-id-and-password-for-visual-studio-code-with-an-authenticat\

But, not sure if there any safer methods to overcome this problem..