# Unable to parse content from 'http://json.schemastore.org/prettierrc': Parse error at offset 0. (768)

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, proxy, prettier

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am trying to use prettier in one of my projects and when I created a simple .prettierrc file, I got an error message that I ended up discovering that it seems to be related with the proxy (I'm under a corporate proxy).

I added a http.proxy to my VS Code settings.json (the same proxy I use for GIT for example), restarted it, and now I am getting the following error message:

[image]

I've found this ([How to specify a user id and password for Visual Studio Code with an authenticating proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730040/how-to-specify-a-user-id-and-password-for-visual-studio-code-with-an-authenticat)) and I'm wondering if now in 2020 that's the only way for me to make it work. Here in my company I don't even have access to my password, just the pin of a smartcard we use...

My proxy in VS Code is setup the following way:

"http.proxy": "http://:@proxyserverurl:8080" (real proxy was hidden for obvious reasons)

I need help, I am quite lost here... :(

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to resolve the issue. It was due to the Git and or NPM since I've reconfigured them and issue is no longer happening.

No `http.proxy` needed in the VS settings, at least not in my case.

Comment: and how you reconfigured them? where's the solution?